# How can I perform validation for the Id field?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have mongoose schema, where I have field called **`Id`** and I made **`Id`** field mandatory for all `GET, PUT, POST and DELETE` requests.

So I have a situation where **`Id`** is mandatory for get, put and delete request, but I have to make **`Id`** as not mandatory for `POST` request. How can I do that?Any help?

Comment: how did you made id mandatory for GET,PUT,POST,DELETE

Comment: In the schema, I made required = true for the id field

Comment: How can I add custom validation for this?

Answer (score 0):

`required:true` is needed for only those fields which are `mandatory` for adding into your document, that is while doing `POST` request.

In your case, you don't need to add `required:true` for `id` field or any other field which you have not set as mandatory for your document to have.

E.g: If you are using mongoose

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        name: {type:String, required: true},
        username: { type: String },//not mandatory, so removed required. 
        age: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Comment: How can I add custom

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make `required:true` for **Id** field in the schema. So for **POST** request, it'll work fine. Then for **GET/PUT/DELETE** requests just check is there **Id** field where you except (say in request query/body/params) then validate that **Id** and do other works.

Answer (score 0):

@gagan, these are more likely to be your inputs from the users consuming your APIs. Validators which you have added are for inserting the documents in Mongo. So both are different sets. 
You probably have to add validations on the user input (which would be req.body) to ensure that you have correct inputs before they are inserted to the database.

You can though add validations either using conditional statements (like if) or you can chose to use third party library. There is one TP library available which is neat , concise and easy to use. Name is Joi:-

Here is how you can use it:-

```
const Joi = require('joi');

function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    id: Joi.number().integer(),
    age: Joi.number.integer().min(18) // Incase you want only 18+ age users
  };

  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}
```

On consumption end:-

```
const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
```

Note:- Joi has two properties "error and value" and only one these is going to have value. So if someone sends valid Object, you are going to have result in value property or else error will be filled up. Hence during consumption , I have added error to ensure that my errors are handled correctly.